# Display and save a grid's gtable/gTree/grob/gDesc in a shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, grid

I have a `function` that's arranging a plot in a `grid`:

```
plotFunc <- function(a,b)
{
  p <- qplot(a,b)
  p2 <- xyplot(1~1)
  r <- grid::rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="grey90"))
  t <- grid::textGrob("text")
  g <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(t, p, p2, r, ncol=2)
  return(g)
}
```

So the return value is:

```
"gtable" "gTree"  "grob"   "gDesc"
```

I want to use a `shiny` `app` in order to be able to select `a` and `b` values display the resulting plot and also have the option to save it to a file.

Here's my code:

`data`:

```
set.seed(1)
vals.df <- data.frame(b=1:6,a=sample(1:2,6,replace=T))
```

Shiny code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(SpaDES)
library(devtools)
server <- function(input, output)
{
  output$b <- renderUI({
    selectInput("b", "B", choices = unique(dplyr::filter(vals.df,a == input$a)$b))
  })

  my.plot <- reactive({function(){plotFunc(a = input$a,b == input$b)}})

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    my.plot()
  })

  output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0(input$a,"_",input$b,".png")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(my.plot(),filename=file)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Feature Plots"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # select name
      selectInput("a", "A", choices = unique(vals.df$a)),

      uiOutput("b"),

      downloadButton('save', 'Save to File')

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # The plot is called feature.plot and will be created in ShinyServer part
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
```

When I run `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)` and select `a` and `b` values from their lists a figure is not displayed to the screen and when I click the `Save to File` button I get this `error`:

```
ERROR: no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "function"
```

I tried wrapping the `my.plot()` calls with `grid.draw` but I get the same `error`:

```
no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Any idea?

Note that I can't get it to work even if `plotFunc` returns the `ggplot2` object (i.e., the `grid` calls are commented out). But solving this for the example above is more general and would also solve it for the `ggplot2` more specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
  my.plot <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$a) & !is.null(input$b)){
      plotFunc(a = input$a,b = input$b)      
    }
  })
```

The change i did was to remove the function. I wasnt sure why you need it and i think it caused the error in the download. Moreover, the second input you give over as a logical statement `==` which will create an error.

Full code would read:

```
set.seed(1)
vals.df <- data.frame(b=1:6,a=sample(1:2,6,replace=T))
plotFunc <- function(a,b)
{
  p <- qplot(a,b)
  p2 <- xyplot(1~1)
  r <- grid::rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="grey90"))
  t <- grid::textGrob("text")
  g <- gridExtra::grid.arrange(t, p, p2, r, ncol=2)
  return(g)
}

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(SpaDES)
library(devtools)

server <- function(input, output)
{
  output$b <- renderUI({
    selectInput("b", "B", choices = unique(dplyr::filter(vals.df,a == input$a)$b))
  })

  my.plot <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$a) & !is.null(input$b)){
      plotFunc(a = input$a,b = input$b)      
    }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    my.plot()
  })

  output$save <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0(input$a,"_",input$b,".png")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(my.plot(),filename=file)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Feature Plots"),

  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # select name
      selectInput("a", "A", choices = unique(vals.df$a)),

      uiOutput("b"),

      downloadButton('save', 'Save to File')

    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      # The plot is called feature.plot and will be created in ShinyServer part
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```